# How can I prove that the $x$-coordinate is always even given this kind of rational function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image]

Is it something about the derivative of the function?

I'm confused because if I set the derivative equal to zero of the first function, I should get the min/max values.

So for $f(x) = \frac{x}{x^{2}+1}$ the derivative is $f'(x) = \frac{-x^2+1}{(x^2+1)^2}$

If I set that equal to zero I get $x= \pm 1$

The maximum is when $x=1$ but then $f(x) = \frac{1}{2}$

However, in the Mathematica output, the first set is $(2,1)$

I don't know how I would arrive at this answer, and furthermore, I don't know how I'd prove this pattern (where the $x$-coordinate of functions of the type $\frac{x}{x^n+1}$ for only even values of $n$.

What can I do to solve this question?

Answer (score 3):

The Mathematica output consists of pairs of numbers. In each pair the first number is the exponent $p$ in the denominator $x^p+1$. The second number is the $x$-coordinate where the maximum occurs. So the pair "$(2,1)$" should be interpreted as "The maximum of $x/(x^2+1)$ occurs at $x=1$". The pair "$(4, \frac1{\sqrt[4]{3}})$" should be interpreted as "the maximum of $x/(x^4+1)$ occurs at $x=\frac1{\sqrt[4]{3}}$", and so on.

Comment: wow i feel really stupid lol that makes much more sense. but even with that, how can i prove it? All i need to say is that the numerator of the derivative is always of the form $-x^p+1 =0$ so x is always the p-th root?

Comment: @user130306 Yep, that approach would work. I assume you also need to confirm that the maximum (and not the minimum) occurs at that value of $x$.

Comment: should i do that using the sign test?

Comment: @user130306 Yes, checking the second derivative is enough.